# Integrar smartmenus en laravel

Tags: laravel

Soy nuevo en Laravel y quiesiera saber como se puede integrar smartmenus, ya ejecute npm install smartmenus

Esto es como se ve en el package.json

```
"dependencies": {
        "npm": "^6.8.0",
        "smartmenus": "^1.1.0",
        "smartmenus-bootstrap-4": "^0.1.0",
        "sweetalert2": "^8.2.6"
    }
```

En app.js agregue esto

```
require('smartmenus');
```

Y en mi componente x.vue esta lo siguiente

```
<ul id="main-menu" class="sm sm-blue">
            <li><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Item 2</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Item 2-1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Item 2-2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Item 2-3</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Item 3</a></li>
        </ul>

...
mounted(){
            this.listarClientes();
            $('#main-menu').smartmenus();
        }
```

Nose que es lo que me falta o si estoy haciendo algo mal

Gracias

Comment: ¿Te esta soltando algún error? He de decir que nunca he tenido buena experiencia juntando jQuery y Vue.

Comment: No, solo no hace nada